# Como posso alterar reescrever base usando .htaccess, do meu diretório raiz para uma pasta?

Tags: mod-rewrite, cms, back-end

Meu problema aqui é que eu tenho uma pasta chamada "projeto" no meu servidor, para um CMS que eu uso. No entanto, quando eu clicar em um link que está no arquivo por exemplo about.html, ele carrega um arquivo de fora da pasta na página raiz principal, minha seção RewriteBase parece com isso agora. Por favor, diga-me como corrigi-lo!

```
Opções -Indexes -MultiViews + FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / projecto /
```

O código acima não parece estar funcionando embora!

Comment: Você fala português? Suas perguntas parecem vindas do google tradutor.

Comment: Não, mas você sabe como consertar isso?

Comment: Só uma comentário: tentou alterar "Opções -Indexes -MultiViews + FollowSymLinks" para "Options -Indexes -MultiViews + FollowSymLinks"?